# Do we always assume we are only dealing with one specific topology of a topological space X instead of all topologies?

Tags: general-topology

I found the following definition of ***interior*** in Munkres's topology.

> Given a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$, the ***interior*** of $A$ is defined as the union of all open sets contained in $A$.

Because $X$ could have multiple topologies, when it was talking about **all open sets**, does it mean the union of all open sets in **all** topologies, or the union of all open sets in **only one** topology?

More generally, when we are dealing with ***open sets*** of a topological space $X$, do we always tend to assume we are dealing with open sets in ***a specific topology*** instead of ***all possible topologies***?

Comment: You consider all open sets of a fixed topology. Notice that if we considered all possible topologies, then the interior of $A$ would be $A$ (thanks to the discrete topology), making this definition redundant.

Answer (score 3):

A topological space $X$ is really a pair $(X,\tau_X)$ of a set $X$ with a topology $\tau_X$ on $X$. By abuse of notation we use $X$ to refer to both the space and the underlying set. Hence, the open sets of $X$ are precisely the elements of $\tau_X$. The fact that the underlying set may have different topologies is almost never interesting or considered. In particular, it makes no sense to call a set open just because it is open in *some* topology that is not under consideration. Especially because that would just mean every set, since every set is open in some topology.

Comment: Just to add to the part of "almost never interesting": sometimes it may be [interesting](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=JWyoCRkLFAkC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=maximal+topologies&source=bl&ots=iincmYiM8j&sig=FJJbQnQo7q_j_DBrTsYmQS2jrw8&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib9qCq4YfQAhXDSSYKHU_YCcgQ6AEIZDAH#v=onepage&q=maximal%20topologies&f=false) :-)